# how to deploy django 1.8 application with nginx and gunicorn on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: django, python-3.x, nginx, ubuntu-14.04

Hi am developing my first web application and i have used django for the same. Now, after completing developing the site i want to host the same on a web server. I do have high speed static ip internet and dedicated server available for the same.

I want to use nginx and gunicorn for the purpose of server applications, i have thoroughly googled the topic and gone through at least 20 tutorials for deploying django applications, but almost all them have explained the process with older versions of django.

I have used django 1.8, it would be of great help if someone could provide a source to refer to continue with the deployment of the site.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I've deployed a couple of Djangos 1.8 following that tutorials without problems.

Comment: You need to explain what about those tutorials is not working for you. Django has up-to-date deployment info in its own documentation: what's wrong with that?

Answer (score 0):

The version of Django does not matter, i suggest you follow the next tutorial [Deployment Django nginx supervisor](http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2013/06/09/django-nginx-gunicorn-virtualenv-supervisor/)